# Named Parameters in C# 4 and Intellisense

Tags: c#, .net, parameter-passing, named-parameters

Am I right in saying there is no Intellisense for C# 4 named parameters in Visual Studio 2010.

For example if I have the following method signature:

```
public static List<Person> GetPerson(string personId = null, string postCode = null, string lastName = null)
```

I would have thought I'd get Intellisense as I typed in the parameter names in the method call.

```
List<Person> people = GetPersons(personId : "abc", [Intellisense appear as I type p..]
```

Or is this not possible because Intellisense would get in the way if you were specifying parameters by position?

Comment: I get Intellisense for those.

Comment: They show up for me... but I use ReSharper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something might have messed with your intellisence settings, see this post:

http://blog.meidianto.com/2010/05/10/vs2010-tips-5-no-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2010-fix-it-now/

If your problems persist, attempt a repair or reinstall of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

No you are not right....I dont know what are you saying but they did show up for me.

[image]